# Horizontal swipe for menu/inbox can't be completed

Tags: bug, android-app

When left menu is opened:

> [image: menu]

trying to open inbox via swipe from the right edge of the screen can't be completed. Only small amount of inbox appears, it hides back when finger is removed from screen:

> [image: inbox]

Same for another direction: trying to open left menu when inbox is on screen.

Mostly happens if swipe is not too fast.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1634100298931)